# PHP dynamic string update with reference

Tags: php, string, pointers, reference

Is there any way to do this:

```
$myVar = 2;
$str = "I'm number:".$myVar;
$myVar = 3;

echo $str;
```

output would be: `"I'm number: 3";`

I'd like to have a string where part of it would be like a pointer and its value would be set by the last modification to the referenced variable.

For instance even if I do this:

```
 $myStr = "hi";
 $myStrReference = &$myStr;
 $dynamicStr = "bye ".$myStrReference;
 $myStr = "bye";
 echo $dynamicStr;
```

This will output "`bye hi`" but I'd like it to be "`bye bye`" due to the last change. I think the issue  is when concatenating a pointer to a string the the pointer's value is the one used. As such, It's not possible to output the string using the value set after the concatenation.

Any ideas?

**Update**: the `$dynamicStr` will be appended to a `$biggerString` and at the end the `$finalResult` (`$biggerString+$dynamicStr`) will be echo to the user. Thus, my only option would be doing some kind of `echo eval($finalResult)` where `$finalResult` would have an `echo($dynamicStr)` inside and `$dynamicStr='$myStr'` (as suggested by Lawson), right?

Update:

```
$myVar = 2;
$str = function() use (&$myVar) {
    return "I'm number $myVar";
};

$finalStr = "hi ".$str();
$myVar = 3;
echo $finalStr;
```

I'd like for this to ouput: "hi I'm number 3" instead of "hi I'm number 2"...but it doesn't.

Comment: Can`t use a variable at a certain step without declaring it or using a future value...

Comment: Maybe `sprintf` would satisfy your needs …? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: No. once a variable is 'expanded' and its value is embedded in a string, the link between the var and the string it was inserted into are severed. PHP does not keep track of the "raw" string and re-execute the concatenation code if the var changes its value later on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that once a variable gets assigned a value (a string in your case), its value doesn't change until it's modified again.

You could use an anonymous function to accomplish something similar:

```
$myVar = 2;
$str = function() use (&$myVar) {
    return "I'm number $myVar";
};

echo $str(); // I'm number 2
$myVar = 3;
echo $str(); // I'm number 3
```

When the function gets assigned to `$str` it keeps the variable `$myVar` accessible from within. Calling it at any point in time will use the most recent value of `$myVar`.

**Update**

Regarding your last question, if you want to expand the string even more, you can create yet another wrapper:

```
$myVar = 2;
$str = function() use (&$myVar) {
    return "I'm number $myVar";
};

$finalStr = function($str) {
    return "hi " . $str();
}

$myVar = 3;

echo $finalStr($str);
```

Comment: You should pass the variable by reference: `...use ( & $myVar )...`

Comment: The issue is the string will be concatenated to a bigger string and at the end an echo will output the final result to the user so that wouldn't be possible, would it?

Comment: @Jack, have you tested your code? The use clause captures the value of `$myVar` at the moment of the declaration of the clausure. As it is, it does not do what you claim.

Comment: @Jack I think linepogl is right... I had to use(&$myVar) for your example to work

Comment: @linepogl Alright, my bad. Didn't test it :) answer is updated. I'm too used to JavaScript semantics.

Comment: @doubter $finalString = $biggerstring . $str(); ... Not sure what the problem is?

Comment: @Jack thought it worked but no. The idea is that even after the $finalString = $biggerstring . $str(); if $myVar changes the $finalString value should change. My idea would be that only when you would do echo($finalString) would the string value be "defined" and every change to that point consider

Comment: @doubter So let the function return the whole string then.

Comment: @Jack unforunatly is not an option as I'm developing a CMS and I'm concatenating the strings as I go through the DB content elements

Answer (score -2):

This is a little simpler than I had before.  The single quotes tell PHP not to convert the $myVar into a value yet.

```
<?php
$myVar = 2;
$str = 'I\'m number: $myVar';
$myVar = 3;

echo eval("echo(\"$str\");");
?>
```