# Assigned a variable and returning a value after assignation

Tags: php, string, reference

I have the following

```
$basename = !empty($_POST['basename']) ? $_POST['basename'] : null;

$upload_files = array(
    '/usr/path/to/dir/' . $basename,
    '/usr/path/to/dir/thumbs/' . $basename
```

Later on, I reassigned the variable `$basename`, like so

```
$basename = 'test.jpg';
```

When `echo` like so

```
echo $upload_files[0];
```

I want to output this

```
'/usr/path/to/dir/test.jpg'
```

But obviously, it doesn't.

Is there a trick with php where this is possible, like adding `&` before the variable or something?

Comment: Beside the great answer you got, this also could be an option. [dynamic-string-update-with-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062349/php-dynamic-string-update-with-reference)

Answer (score 2):

Once you include `$basename` into a string, PHP loses all track of it as a variable, so subsequent changes have no effect. You could make the values in `$upload_files` into arrays, imploding them into strings when required, and making the second element a reference to `$basename`:

```
$basename = 'file1.gif';
$upload_files = array(
    array('/usr/path/to/dir/', &$basename),
    array('/usr/path/to/dir/thumbs/', &$basename)
);

echo implode('', $upload_files[0]) . PHP_EOL;

$basename = 'test.jpg';
echo implode('', $upload_files[0]). PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
/usr/path/to/dir/file1.gif
/usr/path/to/dir/test.jpg
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/4Gljl)

Answer (score 1):

What is your intended use case? If you need to access each pic string, you can store them in an array, and just use the last entry for the 'current' item. Then you'd have access to search or process each if you needed it. You can concat as needed. I'd probably write a function for processing it.

```
$basenames = [];
// However you're retrieving the filename
array_push($basenames, "file.gif");

// Current file
concatPic(count($basenames)-1); 

// To find what key you wants position
$fileIndex = array_search("what_you're_looking_for", $basenames); 

concatPic($fileIndex); // To process a specific index

function concatPic($indexValue) 
{ 
    return / echo (whatever) "usr/path/..." . $basenames[$indexValue] 
};
```

You can also write a foreach to do all of them at once as well, or even concatenate them before pushing to the array if you want.